# What is the PMF of the ratio of two dependent sums of weighted Bernoulli random variables?

Tags: probability-distributions, reference-request, binomial-distribution, bernoulli-distribution

Let $ X_i $ be a Bernoulli random variable of success probability $p$.

Is there any closed-form expression of the probability mass function of the following quantity:

$$
\frac{\sum_i a_i X_i + b}{\sum_i r X_i + p} 
$$

with $p$ and $r$ strictly positive real numbers.

Any insights or literature reference would be gladly appreciated.
Thanks!